# Windows IoT - Mongodb - Raspberry

Tags: node.js, mongodb, raspberry-pi3, windowsiot

Is it possible to install mongodb on Windows 10 IoT?

I've mounted a Windows 10 IoT disk on my Raspberry PI3 and would like to install a nodejs app that connects to a mongodb database.

Do you have any advice? or what would be the database the more appropriated?

Comment: This might help you: https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/05/12/bringing-node-js-to-windows-10-iot-core/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is yes and no.

Either from the MongDB [download](https://www.mongodb.com/download-center?jmp=hero#community) page or [build-from-source](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/wiki/Build-Mongodb-From-Source) page, it only has x86 and x64 versions available, which are all targeting Intel/AMD processors.

Depending on the CPU architecture your windows IoT is running on,

- If it's an ARM based like raspberry pi, you cannot run MongoDB directly unless you can build form the source code targeting AnyCPU.
- If it's Intel based like MinnowBoard Turbot Dual Core Board, technically, you can run MongoDB. However, due to the fact Windows IoT is a minimum version of windows Core, you might run into trouble missing some dependency libraries.

So in both cases, I don't see you can do it with ease, until we have official or community efforts to port MongDB to windows IoT, to which I'm really looking forward.

If you're using windows IoT for cloud-based application, you can go for windows azure databases.

Comment: I've installed MongoDB on Raspbian and Ubuntu MATE version of Raspberry pi

Comment: @Abhishek Parikh, but it's Windows IoT we're talking about!