# Installing MongoDB and python on Windows IOT Core Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, windows, mongodb, raspberry-pi, iot

I have my python code with MongoDB running over Raspbian OS and I want get shifted to the Windows 10 IOT core os of Raspberry PI.

I just want to know how can I install MongoDB over the Windows IOT core.

Thanks

Comment: You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38376019/windows-iot-mongodb-raspberry/38386632#38386632).

Comment: Hello @RitaHan-MSFT thanks for reply but the person has answered wrong. I've myself installed MongoDB on Raspbian and Ubuntu Mate

Comment: But they're quire heavier os for Raspberry Pi I'm trying to deploy it on Windows IOT Core

Comment: You can try to build from [source code](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo).

Comment: I'd love to do that but Windows IOT core doesn't have terminal/command prompt

Comment: You can use [SSH tool](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/docs/ssh).

Comment: Thanks @RitaHan-MSFT I'll Try